# istream_iterator + двумерный вектор

Tags: c++, алгоритм, stl, вектор, итераторы

Встретился с проблемой при занесении элементов из потока через `istream_operator<int>`. Значений заносится больше, чем нужно.

Если есть какие-то советы по улучшению качества кода - буду только благодарен. 
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

 int main() {

  vector<vector<int>> price;
  unsigned int n = 0;
  cin>>n;
  price.reserve(n);
  for (int i = 0 ; i < n;   i++)
  {
    vector<int> vec(2,0);
    price.push_back(vec);
  }
   for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
   {
     for (int j = 0; j < 2;j++)
        {
          istream_iterator<int> in(cin);
          price[i][j] = *in;
          ++in;
        }
    }
   for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
  {
    ostream_iterator<int> out(cout," ");
     for (int j = 0; j < 2;j++)
     {
       copy(price[i].begin(),price[i].begin()+n,out);    
     }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас этот цикл

```
  for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
  {
    ostream_iterator<int> out(cout," ");
     for (int j = 0; j < 2;j++)
     {
       copy(price[i].begin(),price[i].begin()+n,out);    
     }
   }
```

некорректный.

Правильно будет записать

```
  for ( int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
  {
    ostream_iterator<int> out( cout, " " );
    copy( price[i].begin(), price[i].end(), out );    
  }
```

Или

```
  ostream_iterator<int> out( cout, " " );
  for ( int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
  {
    copy( price[i].begin(), price[i].end(), out );    
  }
```

Или

```
  ostream_iterator<int> out( cout, " " );
  for ( vector<vector<int>>::size_type i = 0; i < price.size() ; i++)
  {
    copy( price[i].begin(), price[i].end(), out );    
  }
```

Имейте в виду, что у вас все выводится в одну строку, а не в виде матрицы.

Проще было бы написать

```
for ( const auto &row : price )
{
    for ( auto x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Но, похоже, вы хотите попрактиковаться с итераторами.:)

Также вместо данного фрагмента кода

```
 vector<vector<int>> price;
  unsigned int n = 0;
  cin>>n;
  price.reserve(n);
  for (int i = 0 ; i < n;   i++)
  {
    vector<int> vec(2,0);
    price.push_back(vec);
  }
```

вы могли бы записать

```
  unsigned int n = 0;
  cin>>n;

  vector<vector<int>> price( n, vector<int>( 2 ) );
```

В данных циклах определение входного итератора можно вынести наружу.

```
   istream_iterator<int> in(cin);

   for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
   {
     for (int j = 0; j < 2;j++)
        {
          price[i][j] = *in;
          ++in;
        }
    }
```

Естественно было бы проще не использовать итератор, а написать просто

```
for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2;j++)
    {
        cin >> price[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо вам за дельные советы)

Comment: @Max Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)